# Wordpress - flush_rewrite_rules is too slow?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, wordpress-hook

One of the Wordpress websites I manage occasionally has a problem where all of the posts/pages/etc all go to 404. Flushing the permalinks like this fixes the problem every time, and the users never see the 404s:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'flush_rewrite_rules_on_404');
function flush_rewrite_rules_on_404() {
    if( is_404() ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
```

My logs show that the flush runs on the page, as well as for each image on the page.

If a user visits a non-existent URL (e.g. www.mywebsite.com/mispelled-uri), the flush still occurs. If I want to restrict the flush so that it only occurs for legitimate pages that 404 (e.g. check the REQUEST_URI for valid term-slugs and post_names), then I need to refresh the page 1-3 times to get that code to run, and make the 404 go away, instead of getting the seamless performance that I get from the code sample above.

Why is there such a massive performance issue, just from adding an additional check in the IF() block?

How can I resolve this?

(We've spent several days looking to resolve the original bug; we've already seen all the pages that say "Did you update/install/uninstall plugins? Themes? Restore DB from backup?" It's none of those issues, and the customer is unwilling to spend more time on this when there's other stuff to do)

Comment: Something must be inherently flawed with any legitimate rewrite rules you have if they are lost. Your rules must always be defined to anticipate them being flushed by another process or you have to write hooks to anticipate the rules being flushed to re-register your own if they have a cost to define (Eg from a database lookup). I can't think of a valid scenairo to need `flush_rewrite_rules()` on a 404 page.